# CodeName One server error: Signing for "<AppName>" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor

Tags: ios, build, codenameone

I'm trying to submit a build to CodeName One's servers for ios, but I'm getting the following error:

```
=== BUILD TARGET <> OF PROJECT <> WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies
Code Signing Error: Signing for "<AppName>" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.
warning: skipping file '/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build2312703286849472619xxx/dist/<>-src/<>-Prefix.pch' (unexpected file type 'sourcecode.c.objc.preprocessed' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
warning: skipping file '/var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build2312703286849472619xxx/dist/<>-src/<>-Info.plist' (unexpected file type 'text.plist.xml' in Frameworks & Libraries build phase)
Warning: The Link Binary With Libraries build phase contains this target's Info.plist file '<>-src/<>-Info.plist'.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Failed xcodebuild step
```

The code builds fine locally; the error shows up when it is submitted to the remote build servers.  I've seen several questions on SO about this xcodebuild issue, but none are for CodeName One.  (I assume CodeName One is using xcode when they do their server build.)  How do I select a development team from the CodeName One NetBeans plugin?

I used the CodeName One wizard to generate the ios certificates; not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the build error log, Shai was able to identify the issue.  The xcode version had been set to 9.2 instead of 7.3.  By changing the value of the codename1.arg.ios.xcode_version variable in the codenameone_settings.properties file from 9.2 to 7.3, the build completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a university or an enterprise iOS developer account? If so you need to get into the iOS Signing section in Codename One Settings and configure the right options.

[image]

Comment: The iOS Signing section is already filled out, with a Team ID that matches the TeamIdentifier in the provisioning profile.   I believe that section was filled out when we used the CodeName One wizard to generate the signing certificates.  Is there a different development team ID?

Comment: Can you provide the `codenameone_settings.properties` file? If this is a problem here notice you can use our website support for build issues in the bottom right corner of the page.

Comment: It looks like the directory of the project is "Mobile Apps" which includes a space in it. It seems we have a regression in the settings tool where URL's get bungled and stuff isn't sent correctly. Usually it doesn't manifest itself like that though.

Comment: I removed the spaces from the directory, updated the settings, and tried doing another server build.  Still getting the same error.  Is there a .properties setting I can manually set to get around this?

Comment: This looks like it should work, do you have any cn1libs? Can you contact the site support in the blue chat option and provide this link and the link to the build error? Maybe there is an additional detail there